# Input not being displayed

Tags: raphael

I have an input field.  When the user clicks it some javascript converts the text to a Raphael JS library variable.  I want to put each letter into a Raphael variable called string followed by a \n.  When the user clicks on the button nothing is displayed.  Can someone help me fix this?...

```
    <html> 
    <head> 
    <script src="raphael.js"></script> 
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">   
    var string = "";
    function animate() {  

    var txt = document.getElementById("words").value;
    var splittxt = txt.split("");

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < splittxt.length; i++) {
        var string = splittxt[i] + "\n\n";

        }
        }      

        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        #letters
        {
        text-align:center;
        margin-left:10px;
        width:25px;
        float:left;
        text-shadow:10px 5px 1px #4D4D4D;
        filter:DropShadow(Color=#4D4D4D, OffX=10, OffY=5);
        font-weight:bold;
        }

        </style>

        </head> 

        <body>  

        Text: <input type="text" id="words"  /> 
        <input type="button" value="Animate" onclick="animate()" /> 
        <div id='letters'></div>
        <div id="draw-here-raphael" style="height: 200px; width: 400px; margin-top:0px; background-color:blue;"> 
        </div> 
        <div id="elps" style="ma

rgin-left:100px;"/>  

    <script type="text/javascript"> //all your javascript goes here  
    var r = new Raphael("draw-here-raphael");  
    var string = r.text(50,50, string);
    </script>

    </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: the `value` of the words `input` is blank! normal?

Comment: i took out the value part, but it still doesn't work.  Do you know why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the variable string, you want add to it. Also, there were quite a few other updates I made to your excerpt...

Setting variables to reserved words can also cause a lot of problems.

http://jsfiddle.net/fN9Me/

```
<html> 
    <head> 
    <script src="raphael.js"></script> 
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">   
        var alpha = "";
        var something = "";
        var r = "";
        var txt = "";
        var splittxt = "";

        $(function() {
            r = new Raphael("draw-here-raphael");

            $("#animate").click(function() {
                txt = $("#words").val();
                splittxt = txt.split("");

                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < splittxt.length; i++) {
                    something += splittxt[i] + "\n\n";
                }
                alpha = r.text(50, 50, something);
            });

        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #letters
    {
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:10px;
    width:25px;
    float:left;
    text-shadow:10px 5px 1px #4D4D4D;
    filter:DropShadow(Color=#4D4D4D, OffX=10, OffY=5);
    font-weight:bold;
    }

    </style>

    </head> 

    <body>  
       Text: <input type="text" id="words" value="" />
        <input id="animate" type="button" value="Animate" />
        <div id='letters'></div>
        <div id="draw-here-raphael" style="height: 200px; width: 400px; margin-top:0px; background-color:blue;">
        </div>
        <div id="elps" style="margin-left:100px;"/>  
    </body> 
</html>
```

**Update:**

To remove the previous text, it is just a matter of utilizing the Raphael `remove` function.  Also we have to reset the variable `something`

```
if (alpha) alpha.remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fN9Me/1/

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for the help.  Do you think you could put all of that code onto one page like I had it?? If not, no big deal..

Comment: one problem with that solution though...how do you make it so that if I type something new in it doesn't print what I typed in before???

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually displaying anything. This line:

```
document.getElementById("letters").innerHTML + splittxt[i] + "<br>";
```

needs to be something like:

```
document.getElementById("letters").innerHTML += splittxt[i] + "<br>";
```

Comment: any relation to matt barkley the qb at usc??

Answer (score 0):

The `value` of the `words` input is blank => when you call the split method `var splittxt = txt.split("");` the `splittxt` has a `length == 0`, and therefore the body of the `for` statement is never executed.